# Subdomain Mod-Rewrite issue Internal redirection doesn't work

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, internal, silent

I am trying to get Subdomains work for my Site using htaccess, For example:

shopping.site.local should lead the user to site.local/shopping-and-fashion keeping the initial subdomain format, means in an internal redirection that the user can't notice.

I have added the following script:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shopping.site.local$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.shopping.site.local$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.local/shopping-and-fashion/$1 [L]
```

The redirection happens successfully but in an external way, how to hide the redirection to have always the url:

http://shopping.site.local

and the content of:

http://www.site.local/shopping-and-fashion

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use [P] instead of [L] ?

Answer (score 0):

The following uses reverse proxying and should give you what you want

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName shopping.site.local
  ProxyPass / http://www.site.local/shopping-and-fashion/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse / http://www.site.local/shopping-and-fashion/
</VirtualHost>
```

You might have to hack some JS and CSS to accommodate for the path changes if the original files are not relative links friendly.